# Как при клике на элемент или на детей этого элемента выполнять функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-events

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const popup = $('.popup')
document.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(e.target.classList == 'popup__content')
    /* console.log(event.target == 'popup__content');
    popup.on('click', function (e) {
        console.log(event.target);
        // if (e.target) {
            
        // }
        // popup.addClass('hide-popup')
    })
    if (!(e.target.classList[0] == 'popup__content') && !(popup.hasClass('hide-popup'))) {
        popup.addClass('hide-popup')
    }
    if (e.target.localName === 'button') {
        popup.removeClass('hide-popup')
    } */
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `contains()` для проверки на вложенность.

```
const popup = document.querySelector(".popup");
document.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log(popup.contains(e.target));
};
```

[Методы contains и compareDocumentPosition](https://learn.javascript.ru/compare-document-position)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: popup.contains is not a function

Comment: @АлександрД.извиняюсь, это метод не jquery, а чистого js, исправил.